# Solution to multivariable polynomial mod p

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, multilinear-algebra

I would like to know how to solve this polynomial

$(x^2-y^2+z^2)^n\equiv0\mod p$

Can we have general solution for n? Also how to solve it for n=1 or 2?

Comment: $n$ doesn't appear to be relevant here.  $a^n\equiv 0 \pmod p\iff a\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: I agree with @lulu, assuming $p$ denotes a prime

Comment: it would take more substance by taking $p$ as an irreducible polynomial  maybe